# Quais são os compiladores para C++14 mais comuns no Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, c++14

Quais são os compiladores gratuitos mais comuns no Linux para compilar C++14? "Mais comuns" no sentido de mais utilizados e disponíveis em diversas distribuições. Estou utilizando CENTOS e preciso compilar códigos que usam as novas funcionalidades do C++14.

Comment: [Esta pergunta está sendo debatida no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6872/reabrir-ou-n%C3%A3o-esta-pergunta).

Answer (score 4):

Eu uso [GCC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) (GNU Compiler Collection). GCC suporta o C++14 completo desde GCC 5 ([GCC Suporte do C++ - inglês](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14)). Quase todas (se não todas) as distribuições de Linux suportam GCC.

Para ativar as novas funcionalidades do C++14, utilize a opção `-std=c++14` para excluir extensões de GNU ou `-std=gnu++14` para incluir extensões de GNU.

Para compilar C++, é normal chamar `g++`, que é o mesmo que chamar `gcc -xc++ -lstdc++ -shared-libgcc` ([Diferença entre GCC e G++ - Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/172587/what-is-the-difference-between-g-and-gcc)). Então para compilar C++14, usaria `g++ -std=c++14` ou `g++ -std=gnu++14`.

Também pode olhar [Clang](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), mas eu não conheço muito bem. Parece que suporta C++14 desde versão 3.4 ([Clang Suporte do C++ - inglês](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx14)).

Comment: O Linux foi feito compilado em GCC. Os primeiros testes do Linus Torvalds para saber se o kernel funcionava minimamente foi ver se o GCC era capaz de compilar o fonte do GCC rodando sobre o Linux. Então posso dizer com grande certeza que todas as distribuições Linux conseguem suportar o GCC, mas nem todas necessariamente precisam ter um pacote GCC

Comment: @Jefferson, eu não disse que todas têm um pacote GCC, eu disse que quase todas têm. Na minha experiência, é raro ter uma distribuição que não tem um pacote GCC.

Comment: Eu não entendo porque tenho um voto negativo. Tem um erro na minha resposta?

Comment: A pergunta é baseada em opiniões, e esse tipo de pergunta costuma ter respostas também baseadas em opinioes, o que não é bem aceito neste site. Queremos perguntas e respostas concretas, sem se basear em gosto pessoal.

Comment: Eu não dei uma opinão. Eu dei dois compiladores que suportam C++14 em Linux. Eu expliquei que não conheço bem um dos compiladores, mas não entendo como isto chega a ser um opinão. Por favor qual parte de minha resposta não é concreta? Português é minha segunda língua, então tal vez não esto entendendo algo sutil que muda o sentido do que eu disse.

Comment: Respondendo uma pergunta de baixa qualidade e que não é bem aceita no site por ser baseada opiniões, você está incentivando que outros façam a mesma coisa. Claro que falo apenas por mim, mas talvez outros usem este mesmo criterio.

Comment: Eu ainda não entendo como a pergunta é de opinião. Eu entendi a pergunta como "Quais opções existem". Marcelo perguntou qual "posso utilizar", não qual "devo utilizar". Também, não parece justo dar votas negativos a uma resposta só porque a pergunta foi má. Eu já vi perguntas más que resultaram em respostas boas. Então, qual parte de minha resposta parece opinião?

Comment: Eu também não acho a pergunta baseada em opinião.

Comment: A pergunta não me cativou. Achei ela muito dependente de opinião, mas isso foi meu julgamento. Se o autor ou vocês souberem de algo que eu não esteja percebendo, então podemos tentar reabrir (mentira, eu já dei meu posicionamento, não posso votar para reabrir agora). Viva a divergência de opiniões. Eu fui um tanto mais dramático quando discordei do fechamento de uma outra questão, talvez seja o caso de ser aqui também: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6857/64969. De toda sorte, eu enxergo (agora) essa pergunta como pertinente ao chat, como um papo de bar legal mesmo, não no site principal.

Comment: @KyleA eu quis dizer o que você colocou no primeiro comentário: GCC tem em quase todo canto. Eu aprofundei querendo dizer que: "mesmo que a distribuição não ajude, é possível"

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Pra mim a questão é: quais são os compiladores mainstream para C++14 no linux? Não é a minha especialidade, mas imagino que sejam uns poucos (nem saberia dizer quais além do gcc e do clang). Agora, sim, a pergunta tem termos que podem puxar opiniões (vide a outra resposta), mas são editáveis. Outra coisa que dá cara de "fechável" para a pergunta é que ela esbarra nas famigeradas questões das [recomendações](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/57) e [listas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/819). Não sei se estou sendo "dramático" aqui :)

Comment: @bfavaretto não foi dramático, foi discreto xD. Bem, então há algum fundamento para eu ter a impressão de ser preferível fechar. Espero uma boa edição para então poder dar meu +1 nela.

Comment: @bfavaretto, obrigado por dar o exemplo de listas. Ainda não creio que a pergunta seja de opinião, mas é sim uma pergunta que pode gerar uma lista.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado [Levei pro meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6872/reabrir-ou-n%C3%A3o-esta-pergunta). Kyle, sim mas tenho minhas dúvidas. Preferi chamar a comunidade pra debater.